# Failing with a simple htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wanted to do a simple `.htaccess` redirect, but I can not make it work.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect about.html article.php?id=about [L]
```

The script and `.htaccess` is living in a subdirectory: `domain.tld/directory/`

Where is my error?

Comment: Could you try, `RewriteBase /directory/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the rules of mod_alias and mod_rewrite,

If you want only redirect with mod_rewrite use below in `directory/`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about.html$ article.php?id=about [R=301]
```

And if you want to rewrite, assuming about.html is not exists.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^about.html$ article.php?id=about [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. I really mixed it up. What I wanted was rewriting. Also I had to specify the directory.